# Install Docker auto completion without using Home Brew

Tags: bash, docker, macports

I want to enable the Docker auto completion. The instruction [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/#installing-command-completion) are using `brew` but I'm using `MacPorts`. Trying to install `bash-completion` using `$ sudo port install bash-completion` seems to install a new `bash` on my system and I'm reluctant to do so.

What is the best practice to enable auto completion for Docker using MacPorts?

Comment: The `bash-completion` port installs a new `bash`, because Bash 3.x, which Apple ships in `/bin/bash` does not support the newer bash completion scripts installed by the `bash-completion` port. The newer bash is installed in `/opt/local/bin`, so it should not interfere with your normal installation. See also `port notes bash-completion` for more information.

Comment: @neverpanic would you consider this method safe or is the port version of bash conflicts with the one shipped with macOS?

Comment: I consider this safe, especially since I run it on my own system. System scripts should still use `/bin/bash`. Self-written scripts might use the newer Bash 4.x (if you run them with `bash scriptname.sh` or use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as shebang), but if your scripts work with Bash 3.x the probability that they break with 4.x is low in my experience.